# Cohomology group of a submanifold or Lie subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, cohomology, isotropic-submanifolds

In general: if one knows the cohomology group of some manifold ${\cal M}$, i.e. $H^n ({\cal M})$, are there known results for the same cohomology group $H^n (X)$ of a submanifold $X \subset {\cal M}$? If so I would really appreciate any pointers to the literature.

I am in particular interested in the following case of an empty second cohomology group of a Lie group $G$. Given that $H^2 (G) = 0$ and $F$ is a simply connected subgroup of $G$, is it obvious what is $H^2(F)$? Is it vanishing as well? Not sure if the following helps to narrow it down but in the particular example I am studying, $Lie(F)$ is also isotropic with respect to a symmetric bilinear form on $Lie(G)$.

Comment: The second cohomology of any LIe group is trivial.

Comment: (Slight correction to Ben McKay's comment: this is true of simply connected Lie groups.) Also, a group is not empty. You mean to say $H^2(G) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes the second part of my question quite trivial :)

Comment: There are of course relations, given by Mayer-Vietoris etc. But these answers will need a lot more imput of what $X$ is: Whitney's theorem says that any manifold is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The characteristic classes of the tangent/normal bundle of $X$ also have strong relations with characteristic classes of $M$.

Comment: One possibility would be to relate the cohomology of $G$ with the cohomology of $F$ by means of the Leray spectral sequence associated with the quotient map $\pi : G \mapsto G/F$.